# QGIS 2 runtime error message on Windows 8:new install

Tags: qgis, error

I am getting the following error message:

> Run Time Error
>   Program:C:\PROGRA~1\bin\qgis-bin.exe
>   R6034
>   An application made an attempt to load C runtime library incorrectly
>   Contact application suppliers"

My operating system is Windows 8 2012. I have a 64 bit operating system QGIS version Desktop 2.0.1, Browser 2.0.1. This is following download when I try to open the Desktop

I am not hugely computer operating system literate so please can the answers avoid too much jargon!!

Comment: and sorry but I can't help, only add to the problem. I have 64 bit W7, and a new install of QGIS 2, with the same error. I have C++ 2005, 2008 and 2010 loaded. The error reads: "Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library Runtime Error! PROGRAM: C:\PROGRA~1\QGISDU~1\bin\qgis-bin.exe R6034 An application has made an attempt to load the C runtime library incorrectly. Please contact the application's support team for more information." QGIS does load, so I suspect some of the modules will fail, but which ones and what? Cheers Rich